# ArgoCD fails updating bitbucket.org private repos with: ssh: handshake failed: knownhosts: key mismatch

Tags: bitbucket, argocd

In 15/05/2023 bitbucket.org added ecdsa and ed25519 ssh keys to their Bitbucket cloud hosts.

Since then ArgoCD fails pulling the private repos, all the applications are in the Unknown status.

The repo server pod shows the message:

```
ssh: handshake failed: knownhosts: key mismatch
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem can be solved by updating bitbucket `ssh-known-hosts-cm` with its new ones.

- Edit configmap (assuming argocd namespace is `argocd` and the configmap name is `argocd-ssh-known-hosts-cm`, replace the entry of `bitbucket.org` with `yaml` section below

```bash
$ kubectl -n argocd edit cm argocd-ssh-known-hosts-cm
```

```yaml
....
data:
  ssh_known_hosts: |
    bitbucket.org ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAubiN81eDcafrgMeLzaFPsw2kNvEcqTKl/VqLat/MaB33pZy0y3rJZtnqwR2qOOvbwKZYKiEO1O6VqNEBxKvJJelCq0dTXWT5pbO2gDXC6h6QDXCaHo6pOHGPUy+YBaGQRGuSusMEASYiWunYN0vCAI8QaXnWMXNMdFP3jHAJH0eDsoiGnLPBlBp4TNm6rYI74nMzgz3B9IikW4WVK+dc8KZJZWYjAuORU3jc1c/NPskD2ASinf8v3xnfXeukU0sJ5N6m5E8VLjObPEO+mN2t/FZTMZLiFqPWc/ALSqnMnnhwrNi2rbfg/rd/IpL8Le3pSBne8+seeFVBoGqzHM9yXw==
    bitbucket.org ssh-dss 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
    bitbucket.org ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBPIQmuzMBuKdWeF4+a2sjSSpBK0iqitSQ+5BM9KhpexuGt20JpTVM7u5BDZngncgrqDMbWdxMWWOGtZ9UgbqgZE=
    bitbucket.org ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIIazEu89wgQZ4bqs3d63QSMzYVa0MuJ2e2gKTKqu+UUO
...
```

- Finally, restart repo-server pod (by deleting the pod) to load the new cm and verify via argocd UI.

Bitbucket [announced](https://bitbucket.org/blog/ssh-host-key-changes?jobid=106067432&subid=1725558038) the change and you can use the section `what you need to do` #2 to extract known host entries for the cm.

Comment: it solves my problem but only for a moment, since after a few second my known-hosts configmap returns to its original state. i know that this is unrelated to the listed problem, but do you have any idea what may be causing it?

Comment: There are 02 ways to update those entries, or via cm editing directly, or using the UI to do it. Can you try via UI instead? If the cm suddenly change, there should be another way to automatically update methods to reconcile argocd, perhaps argocd checks its state againts scm (git?)

Comment: after modifying it in the UI it also reverts to the old state
I have argo self-managed, so this may be the issue, thanks for help!

Comment: looks like an [open issue](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/13604) is in progress and I hope they will soon address this with coming release

Answer (score 1):

I think what Long Tran has answered is correct.

### Just for my case, I just resolve it using another method with Argocd command line

And you don't need to do any pods deletion to reload ConfigMap of argocd-repo-server pods.

1. Make sure you have the Argocd installed
2. Run `argocd login`

```
argocd login {argocd url}
# then enter admin user admin/password
```

For argocd url, you can port-forward argocd server as following

```
kubectl get svc -n argocd
kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443
# Login argocd and accept insecure access
argocd login localhost:8080
```

3. Get list of current SSH certificates

```
# see list of keys
argocd cert list --cert-type ssh
```

4. Scan Bitbucket.org ssh keys and batch add to Argocd

```
 
# scan bitbucket org ssh and add to argocd
ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org | argocd cert add-ssh --batch
```

5. There is a missing ssh-dss, you can achieve by add from file

```
argocd cert add-ssh --batch --from .\ssh_file_dss
```

This is the content of .\ssh_file_dss, create this file with that content below

```
bitbucket.org ssh-dss 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
```

- Other useful command to remove if needed:

```
argocd cert rm bitbucket.org --cert-type ssh --cert-sub-type ssh-ed25519
argocd cert rm bitbucket.org --cert-type ssh --cert-sub-type ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
argocd cert rm bitbucket.org --cert-type ssh --cert-sub-type ssh-dss
```

Reference: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/private-repositories/#unknown-ssh-hosts